# TypeScript + NodeJS readline property missing

Tags: node.js, typescript, readline

I'm working on a small project in TypeScript with `tsc -v 2.4.2` and Node v6.10.3.

I would like to capture keypresses in the CLI, so I tried to `import * as readline from 'readline'` and then later use `readline.emitKeyPressEvents(process.stdin)`, but it complains that `the property emitKeyPressEvents is not found on typeof readline`.

I have also done `npm install --save @types/node`.

Here's a M(N)WE:

```typescript
import * as readline from "readline";
import {SIGINT} from "constants";

export class InputManager
{
    private _currentStates: Array<IKeyEntity>;
    private _oldStates: Array<IKeyEntity>;

    public constructor()
    {
        // Throws error, won't compile
        readline.emitKeyPressEvents(process.stdin);
    }

    public handleInput()
    {
        if (process.stdin.isTTY)
            process.stdin.setRawMode(true);

        process.stdin.on('keypress', (str: string, key: any) => {
            process.stdout.write('Handling keypress ['+str+']');

            if (key && key.ctrl && (key.name == 'c' || key.name == 'l'))
            {
                process.kill(process.pid, SIGINT);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method is indeed missing from the `node` typings. Its correct name is actually `emitKeypressEvents` (with a lower-case `p`), but that one is also missing. I assume this is a simple oversight, so I've submitted a [PR](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/19733) with the addition to DefinitelyTyped. This might take a while to process (around a week, if all goes well), but in the mean time you can type check your code by adding a local declaration to the file containing `InputManager`:

```
declare module 'readline' {
  export function emitKeypressEvents(stream: NodeJS.ReadableStream, interface?: ReadLine): void;
}
```

Comment: It took a bit longer than usual, but `@types/node@8.0.36`, released today, includes `emitKeypressEvents`.