# Why can't I "import * as readline from 'readline'" in Nodejs v10?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, ecmascript-6, readline

In the Nodejs docs, I see:

> import EventEmitter from 'events';
>
> import { readFile } from 'fs';
>
> import fs, { readFileSync } from 'fs';

https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

But with "readlines", I see:

> const readline = require('readline');

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/readline.html

But in StackOverflow, I see:

> import * as readline from "readline";

[TypeScript + NodeJS readline property missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46206805/typescript-nodejs-readline-property-missing)

But I tried the above and other variations of `import` and can't make it work, so I have to use `require`. Could someone explain to me why this is the case, since `readline` is a default node module?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ran node with `--experimental-modules` flag?

Comment: Thanks! Doing that and renaming extension to `.mjs` worked!
https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of `import` syntax is not yet available by default in Node.js LTS. You can either use a transpiler such Babel to be able to use it or use the `--experimental-modules` flag when running your Node.js script / server besides changing the extension of your files from `.js` to `.mjs`.

Comment: Thanks! I've `node --experimental-modules file_name.mjs`, according to https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling

Comment: Still true 4 1/2 years later.